# Youtube embedded with Javascript no stats

Tags: javascript, youtube, statistics

For a number of reasons I am loading an embedded Youtube video onto a page using Javascript. Probably the primary reason for this is so that it can begin playing instantly when a lightbox is opened.

The issue I've found is that statistics for the video are not being recorded:

[image: Youtube Statistics]

Before you question, I know it says next to letter A that is has been embedded, I've only just done this as part of my testing. The video has been on the website as a Javascript lightbox popup for at least 2 months now.

To try and test, I embed code supplied by Youtube directly onto a new web page (not loaded by Javascript), this works fine and hence why stats are now being recorded. Looking at what is happening on the two pages I can only see slight differences:

The embed which correctly sends stats:
[image: The embed which correctly sends stats]

The javscript embed:
[image: The javscript embed]

Both get the error which I thought at first might be the issue. After that, while there are some requests missing from the latter, I'm not sure how much difference they make (eg. hovering over 'read2 ' seems to be requesting youtube annotations).

Anyone else experienced the same problem?

**Update:**

I have changed the way I dynamically load the video onto the page. Before, I had the  code loaded as a string in Javascript. When ready I would load this into another element on the page.

The change I made was to have the iframe loaded onto the page first. Then, using Javascript I removed the element (simply hiding doesn't work as it needs autoplay) into a variable and when ready appended it again. While the technique worked, it made no difference to recording statistics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually managed to find the answer myself. For anyone with similar problems, read on.

Basically, it's impossible to use autoplay=1 and have the view count increase. This is presumably to stop spammers. Investigating into the JS alternative of triggering the video (videoPlay()) came into the same problem. I finally found a small snippet which says

> "Note: YouTube only counts playbacks that are initiated through a
>   native play button in either the embedded or chromeless player."

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#playVideo

The only two native play buttons (no possibility of a custom one) are the one bottom left (next to the volume control) and the one which appears in the middle of the video when it first loads, prompting play.

For myself, I am going to look at using GA to record plays (when my custom button is pressed, recorded using custom events) as I only want to know if it's watched for not and this should suffice.

Good luck to anyone else.